# Scanner (String someString);

Tags: java

I have a question about the Scanner and it is :

Why is it allowed to have the following declaration:

```
String someString;
Scanner readString = new Scanner(someString);
```

but its not allowed the following:

```
Scanner readString = new Scanner(String someString);
```

The second case uses String someString without it being global or local variable. Why the Scanner cant use such string?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The short answer is: You can't declare a variable in the middle of a constructor like that.  The long answer is: read the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

Comment: why don't you try to run it and read the compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the Java syntax.

The first code is split into two declarations:

```
String someString;
```

a string variable

The second line is a declaration of a Scanner object named readString:

```
 Scanner readString = new Scanner(someString);
```

where the parameter of the constructor is using readString as a new Scanner with parameter someString

The second piece of code is simply a wrong usage of the second declaration of the first piece of code where instead of a real parameter, you write a variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner readString = new Scanner(someString);
```

is allowed because you are passing a variable of type String to the Scanner's constructor.

```
Scanner readStringa = new Scanner(String someString);
```

is not allowed because `new Scanner(String someString)` is invalid java statement and the compiler will not able to parse it properly and you will get "illegal start of expression" error

Comment: Yes, thats right, but why is it invalid? Can you please give me little more insight?

Comment: @user3710255 you should read about Lexical and Grammer section from JLS

Comment: My confusion comes from the fact that if i create a class, then the constructor of that class can take some parameters, as example of my class Class :  Class{String someString, int someInt}. But why is that not allowed in the Scanner constructor?

Comment: Ok i think i got it, what im doing is im writing a constructor to a class that is already written, and with the first statement I am giving arguments to a constructor which already exist in that class

Comment: Basically in first statement you are passing a variable to the constructor and in second statement you are declaring a variable in wrong place. The compiler will not able to parse it properly and you will get "illegal start of expression" error

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you, you want to do this in one line.
Then the way to do this is :

```
Scanner readString = new Scanner(new String("The String you want"));
```

Comment: You have to take a choice.
you can't put a non-initialised attribute, it makes no sense. 
And you can't declare it at this area of the code.
If I understand your need, you want to put a String value directly to have an initialised Scanner variable inline. Isn't it?

Comment: Ok, since your Java knowledge seems to be quite low, I'll explain it in easy words: there is no sense in calling `new String` here. `"The String you want"` itself is a String literal and ok as it is. Passing that into the String constructor just creates ___another___ String instances which itself is just a was of memory. `new Scanner("The String you want")` is already fine (and better).

Comment: "a was of memory" -> "a waste of memory" damn typos :/.

Comment: Don't judge my knowledge. Your topic was not useful. Variable declaration was the first chapter of a book i finished the first year i learned Java. You made a mistake on variable declaration. I've not made a mistake, but i tried to help you with an other way.

Comment: I haven't made any mistake on a variable declaration, because I'm not OP (is the different user name really not that obvious)? But still, that doesn't change the fact that calling the `String` constructor explicitly is completely useless.